# Spring Security in Webflux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have been trying to enable spring security in web flux, with my own custom authentication method. So far so good, but I am not able to allow certain URL patterns using permitall.

I have tried to create different beans of SecurityWebFilterChain, also tried with different config altogether, but nothing seems to work for me.

Here is my SecurityWebFilterChain

```
@Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .httpBasic()
        .disable()
        .formLogin()
        .disable()
        .logout()
        .disable()
        .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager())
        .securityContextRepository(this.securityContextRepository())
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("**/signal/health").permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("**/order").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .anyExchange()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .build();
  }
```

I have an internal health check system, which runs as soon as my application is up, so I want this to be allowed.

Moreover, I also want to allow another couple or URI, but the above config doesn't work for me.

Everything goes for authentication.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I see a wrong `and` and `authorizeExchange` placed in between. Try using this:

```
@Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .logout().disable()
        .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager())
        .securityContextRepository(this.securityContextRepository())
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("**/signal/health","**/order").permitAll()
        .anyExchange()
        .authenticated()
        .and().build();
  }
```

Comment: It is still giving me unauthorized.
Also, the health check is still going inside the overridden load method.


```
 @Override
      public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
          log.info(serverWebExchange.getRequest().getURI());
```

Comment: Which overriden load method? Can you also share the code of the authenticationManager and securityContextRepository beans

Comment: ```
 @Bean
  ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return authentication -> {
      log.debug("Autentication: " + authentication.toString());
      if (authentication instanceof CustomPreAuthenticationToken) {
        authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
      }
      return Mono.just(authentication);
    };
  }
```

Comment: ```
public class CustomPreAuthenticationToken  extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    public CustomPreAuthenticationToken(String key, Object principal, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(key, principal, authorities);
    }
}

```

Comment: The securityContextRepository bean is a bit too long so I am posting it in 2 parts.

Comment: ```
@Bean
  ServerSecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
    return new ServerSecurityContextRepository() {
      @Override
      public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, SecurityContext securityContext) {
        return null;
      }
```

Comment: The @load method is again a bit too long...
```
@Override
      public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
          log.info(serverWebExchange.getRequest().getURI());
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders();
        if (httpHeaders.get(SSO_TOKEN_HEADER) == null) {
          throw new SocialAuthFailure("sso_token is either empty or null in header");
        }

```

Comment: ```
return serverWebExchange
            .getPrincipal()
            .defaultIfEmpty(() -> "empty principal")
            .flatMap(
                principal ->
                    Mono.just(
                        new SecurityContextImpl(
                            new CustomPreAuthenticationToken(
                                principal.getName(), principal, null))));
      }
    };
```

Comment: In ServerSecurityContextRepository, I am trying to check for a header and based on that header I am doing my authentication, very straightforward.